# Extract texts from a DWG and overwrite them

Tags: autodesk-forge

With what API could I extract the texts contained in a DWG into a JSON, separately I translate them with Google Translate API and finally, enter the texts translated from JSON to DWG?

Answer (score 0):

In order to manipulate and update the DWG file, you can use the Autodesk Platform Services (ex Forge) [Design Automation API for AutoCAD](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/).